# Calculate monthly income from weekly

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need help. Trying to solve the following problem: A table stores information about the weekly sales of a product.
Need to set up automatic conversion of weekly values ​​to monthly values. Sales in transitional weeks (part of the week in one month, part in another) must be distributed on weekdays (excluding weekends - Sat, Sun).
For example, sales for the week ended 03/05/2013 should be distributed as follows: 2 days for February, 3 days for March.
The result of solving the problem is the SQL query that will automatically receive the converted data in the "Result Table" format (month; amount) according to the entered parameter MonthNumber (month number). If the parameter is not specified, the entire table is displayed.

```
drop table if exists #Test
create table #Test
(
sales_date date,
payment_sum real
)

insert into #Test values ('26.02.2013', 312.00)
insert into #Test values ('05.03.2013', 833.00)
insert into #Test values ('12.03.2013', 225.00)
insert into #Test values ('19.03.2013', 453.00)
insert into #Test values ('26.03.2013', 774.00)
insert into #Test values ('02.04.2013', 719.00)
insert into #Test values ('09.04.2013', 136.00)
insert into #Test values ('23.04.2013', 157.00)
insert into #Test values ('30.04.2013', 850.00)
insert into #Test values ('07.05.2013', 940.00)
insert into #Test values ('14.05.2013', 933.00)
insert into #Test values ('21.05.2013', 422.00)
insert into #Test values ('28.05.2013', 952.00)
insert into #Test values ('04.06.2013', 136.00)
insert into #Test values ('11.06.2013', 701.00)
;
```

I started by trying to weed out weekends. But how to understand which of the weeks should be divided between adjacent months?

```
SELECT * FROM #Test
WHERE ((DATEPART(dw, sales_date) + @@DATEFIRST) % 3) NOT IN (6, 7)
```

I want to receive this:

MonthNumber = 0

```
|Month|Incom|
|:----|:----|
|01   |1100 |
|02   |1120 |
|03   |1488 |
|04   |6112 |
|05   |7300 |
|06   |1360 |
|07   |8800 |
|08   |1400 |
|09   |1300 |
|10   |5070 |
|11   |3020 |
|12   |7800 |
```

MonthNumber = 1

```
|01   |1100 |
```

Comment: Your narrative is a little confusing, you have an example date `03/05/2013` but refer to february and march, yet your sample data appears formatted with dates as `dd.mm.yyyy` - which is it?

Comment: Yes you are right. dd.mm.yyyy. And every date is thusday and each date in the table is a Tuesday, and that day is considered the end of the week.

Comment: @DaleK I added the desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a calendar table, including a column that maps each day to the appropriate week and reporting month.  Join that to allocate the weekly sales to the weekdays, something like:

```
drop table if exists #Test
drop table if exists #calendar 
set dateformat dmy

create table #Test
(
sales_date date,
payment_sum real
)

insert into #Test values ('26.02.2013', 312.00)
insert into #Test values ('05.03.2013', 833.00)
insert into #Test values ('12.03.2013', 225.00)
insert into #Test values ('19.03.2013', 453.00)
insert into #Test values ('26.03.2013', 774.00)
insert into #Test values ('02.04.2013', 719.00)
insert into #Test values ('09.04.2013', 136.00)
insert into #Test values ('23.04.2013', 157.00)
insert into #Test values ('30.04.2013', 850.00)
insert into #Test values ('07.05.2013', 940.00)
insert into #Test values ('14.05.2013', 933.00)
insert into #Test values ('21.05.2013', 422.00)
insert into #Test values ('28.05.2013', 952.00)
insert into #Test values ('04.06.2013', 136.00)
insert into #Test values ('11.06.2013', 701.00);


with q as
(
  select top 365 row_number() over (order by (select null))-1 i
  from sys.messages 
), d as
(
select dateadd(day,i,'20130101') dt
from q
)
select d.dt, 
       dateadd(day,3-datepart(dw,dt),dt) week_start, 
       case when datepart(dw,dt) in (6,7) then 0 else 1 end is_weekday,
       datepart(dw,dt) day_of_week, 
       month(dt) month_num
into #calendar
from d 


select month_num, sum(payment_sum/5)
from #test s
join #calendar c
  on s.sales_date = c.week_start
where c.is_weekday = 1
group by month_num
```

outputs

```
month_num   
----------- ----------------------
2           312.000007629395
3           2428.80004119873
4           1378.20001411438
5           3587.00000762939
6           836.999988555908
```

Comment: Each date on my spreadsheet is a weekly revenue

Comment: David, but what about weeks that do not completely fall into one month?

Comment: The first step is to allocate the sales to individual days, then group them into the appropriate month.

Comment: Something went wrong. Your query only returns the name of the columns

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server Management Studio. Maybe this is the problem? Checked on dbfiddle [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=10aef4d81b335a91a7b2cc5b3057d5fc) - everything works

Answer (score 1):

The following will extend sales date 6 days and then aggregate n/5 by month excluding weekends.

**Example**

```
Select D    =EOMonth(D)
      ,Sales=sum(Payment_sum/5) 
 From  #Test A
 Cross Apply ( values ( dateadd(DAY, 0,sales_date) )
                     ,( dateadd(DAY,-1,sales_date) )  
                     ,( dateadd(DAY,-2,sales_date) )  
                     ,( dateadd(DAY,-3,sales_date) )  
                     ,( dateadd(DAY,-4,sales_date) )  
                     ,( dateadd(DAY,-5,sales_date) )  
                     ,( dateadd(DAY,-6,sales_date) )  
             )D(D)
 Where datename(WEEKDAY,D) not in ('Saturday','Sunday')
 Group By EOMonth(D)
```

**Results**

```
D           Sales
2013-02-28  645.20
2013-03-31  2383.20
2013-04-30  1430.60
2013-05-31  3328.60
2013-06-30  755.40
```

Comment: I like this better than what I was going to suggest.